# Deleting specific class and axioms in OWLAPI

Tags: owl, owl-api

I'm trying to delete a class and axioms for that class. I've tried different options, could not get them to work the way I want. Here is the code I have (it deletes nothing...):

```js
if(clazz.toString().contains("2381")) {
        Stream<OWLClassAssertionAxiom> axiomstodelete = ontology.classAssertionAxioms(clazz);
        OWLEntityRemover remover = new OWLEntityRemover(Collections.singleton(ontology));
        axiomstodelete.forEach(i -> i.individualsInSignature().forEach(j -> j.accept(remover)));
        manager.applyChanges(remover.getChanges());
    }
```

Update: 
This code seems to work for a class and associated axioms removal:

```
OWLEntityRemover remover = new OWLEntityRemover(Collections.singleton(ontology));
currentClass.accept(remover);
manager.applyChanges(remover.getChanges());
```

Now, there is a condition, based on which I want to delete all subclasses (branches) of a particular class. The problem is I have to go from the bottom up, because I need to find the "lowest" class in the hierarchy for which the condition is true. I use this code:

```js
currentClass = class_stack.pop();
removeClass(manager, clazz);
prevClass = class_stack.peek();
while(isBottom(reasoner, prevClass) && !class_stack.isEmpty() && !checkCondition(prevClass)) {
  currentClass = class_stack.pop();
  removeClass(manager, currentClass);
  prevClass = class_stack.peek();
}
```

It works for one leaf, but it does not for the parent of the leaf, because isBottom condition for the parent is not true, even after all its children are deleted.  I have a workaround for now - after leaf is deleted, save the ontology, then reload again and delete next leaf etc. Would be nice to make it in one run.

**For Ignazio** - this is an example of a branch that shows why I'm checking for the bottom (C is for class with the true condition, L - for other classes). If I go up the left branch: L (bottom?->yes->delete) -> L(bottom?->yes->delete) -> L (bottom?->NO->leave for now). Then check the right branch: C (bottom?->yes && condition?->yes -> leave!)

```
    C
    |
    L
   / \
  L   L
 /     \
L       C
```

The result I need should be:

```
C
|
L
|
L
|
C
```

Comment: Are you sure that `axiomstodelete` is not empty? Do you want to remove all axioms related to a class? What exactly do you want to remove? Right now, your code removes all axioms that do contain individuals that are also asserted to be an instance of the class `2381`

Comment: Thank you - yes, looks like it is empty. But it does go inside the if statement,  is this not a correct statement to get the axioms for a class? - Stream<OWLClassAssertionAxiom> axiomstodelete = ontology.classAssertionAxioms(clazz);

Comment: it is suggested to use: ont.getIndividualsInSignature() in the documentation, but I don't understand how it can help to accomplish deleting only specific classes.

Comment: If `axiomstodelete` is empty, then there is no class assertion axiom for the class. Do you know what a class assertion axiom is?

Comment: Where was it suggested to call `ont.getIndividualsInSignature()`? And which axioms exactly you want to delete? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: method shouldDeleteIndividuals() from https://github.com/phillord/owl-api/blob/master/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/Examples.java uses ont.getIndividualsInSignature().   I want to delete some specific classes (and I suppose it entails deleting all class's axioms)

Comment: >> Do you know what a class assertion axiom is? - no, I don't know what it is... is it something I add in the code?

Comment: Well, you should learn about different types of axioms in OWL. ClassAssertionAxioms assert a single individual to a single class, e.g. Person(John) states that John is a person.

Comment: You have to call `clazz.accept(remover);` instead of the forEach on an empty set.

Comment: Oh, so easy! Thanks so much. You can post it as an answer)) I'm reading, but so much to learn in a very short timeframe... Is this a good book to start - https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0123859654/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1 ? (if you know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already selected the axioms to remove. Skip the entity removed and use the remove method on the ontology.

Comment: Ignazio, thank you. This is what seems to be working for me:
OWLEntityRemover remover = new OWLEntityRemover(Collections.singleton(ontology));
currentClass.accept(remover);
manager.applyChanges(remover.getChanges()); Is this a good way?

Comment: I also added additional question above - would you take a look at it please?

Comment: You're creating the reasoner as a buffered reasoner. Call flush() between uses.

Comment: Even better, use the reasoner to get all subclasses and delete them all without bottom check.

Comment: Thank you! Using flush() worked, although it takes forever to process.
I cannot figure out an algorithm that would allow me to delete them all. I need to go from a leaf up the hierarchy and, when I find a first class with my "condition", I want to delete all subclasses. But, when we read the ontology we go from top to bottom. I figured that I could use stack for this purpose...

Comment: What's taking time is the leaf check, due to changes to the ontology. You don't need the leaf check at all.

Comment: I've added an explanation on why I need to check for bottom class each time (please see above) - please let me know if this makes sense?

Comment: Once you identify the C at the top, you know all subclasses need to go. Make no changes to the ontology until you have identified all the classes whose subclasses must be deleted, and at that point select all subclasses, prepare all changes and collect them in a list, and call applyChanges only once.